# I seem to be having a problem with counting vowels and consonants with C++, how should i get this to work?

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pointers, switch-statement

I have to write a program that uses an array to store the value of a user entered string and search for vowels and consonants using a vowel array and a consonant array. Also and tips on writing code in general is appreciated. The problem I am having is it seems to only do case A when counting, but exiting with case E seems to work fine. And when case A goes, it doesn't count. Thank you!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>


int vowelsCount(char *); //count the vowels
int consonantCount(char *); //count the consonants
int totalString(char *); //count how big the word is
void endProgram(); //goodbye function

//Used as the main menu
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

const int VOWEL_SIZE = 10; //amount of vowels
const int CONS_SIZE = 44; //amount of consonants
const int USER_STRING_SIZE = 51; //max character limit

char userString[USER_STRING_SIZE]; //User entered string
char uEndInput = 'y';   
char uAns; // user menu answer



//Get a word from user
std::cout << "Please enter a string (up to 50 characters)" << std::endl;
std::cin.getline(userString, USER_STRING_SIZE); //get the sting from the console


//menu
std::cout <<  "\n\n Please select what you would like to do:\n";
std::cout << "\t A)  Count the vowels of a string.\n";
std::cout << "\t B)  Count the consonants of a string.\n";
std::cout << "\t C)  Count both vowels and consonants of a string.\n" ;
std::cout << "\t D)  Enter another string.\n"; 
std::cout << "\t E)  Exit Program.\n" << std::endl;

std::cin >> uAns; // user inputs answer 

switch(uAns){

case 'A': 
case 'a':{
    std::cout << "The total vowel count is: " << vowelsCount(userString) << " \n";
    break;
}
case 'B':
case 'b':{
    std::cout << "The total consonant count is: " << 
consonantCount(userString) << " \n";
    break;
}
case 'C':
case 'c':   
    std::cout << "The total word count is: " << totalString(userString) << " 
\n";
    break;

/*case 'd':
  case 'D': 
    return main();
    break;
}*/
case 'E':
case 'e':{
    return 0;
    break;
}

    }


return 0;
}

int vowelsCount(char *userVowelPtr ){
char vowelsArray[] = {'A', 'a', 'E', 'e', 'I', 'i', 'O', 'o', 'U', 'u', 
'\0'};
char *vArrayPtr = vowelsArray;
int numVowels = 0;

while(*userVowelPtr != '\0')
{
    if (*userVowelPtr == *vArrayPtr ){

            numVowels++; //Add one to the count

    }
    userVowelPtr++; //point to next character
    vArrayPtr++; //point to next vowel
    vArrayPtr = vowelsArray; //set vowelsPtr to first element again
}
std::cout << "\n\n";
return numVowels;
}



int consonantCount(char *consPtr ){
char consonantArray[] = {'B', 'b', 'C', 'c', 'D', 'd', 'F', 'f', 'G', 'g', 'H', 'h', 'J', 'j', 'K', 'k', 'L','l', 'M', 'm', 'N', 'n', 
                        'P', 'p', 'Q', 'q', 'R', 'r', 'S', 's', 'T', 't', 'V', 'v', 'W', 'w', 'X', 'x', 'Y', 'y', 'Z', 'z', '\0'};
char *cArrayPtr = consonantArray;
int numCons = 0;


while(*consPtr != '\0')
{
    if (*consPtr == *cArrayPtr ){

            numCons++; //Add one to count

    }
    cArrayPtr++;//point to next consonant
    consPtr++;//point to next character
    cArrayPtr = consonantArray; //set vowelsPtr to first element again
}
std::cout << "\n\n";
return numCons;
}


int totalString(char *totalPtr ){
int letters = 0;

while (*totalPtr != '\0'){
    letters++;  
}
std::cout << "The total letter is:" << letters << std::endl;
return letters;
}



void endProgram(){
std::cout << "THank you for using the letter counter, have a good day." << 
std::endl;
}
```

Comment: `*vArrayPt` is the same as `vArrayPt[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that you keep on resetting the pointer every single time it would run, instead of just having it increase. I would personally recommend changing the code to have two while loops within the function.

```
while(*userVowelPtr != '\0')
{

     while(*vArrayPtr != '\0')
           {
                if(*userVowelPtr == *vArrayPtr )
                {
                       numVowels++; //Add one to the count
                }

                vArrayPtr++
           }

     userVowelPtr++; //point to next character
     vArrayPtr -= sizeof(vArrayPtr); //set vowelsPtr to first element again
}
```

This is so that the function will run through all of the values of the vArray pointer, comparing it to each individual value of the userVowelPtr.

Comment: Of course you end up commenting and immediately solve the problem. Thanks my dude, see you Thursday

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions for consideration:

1. design the code so that a single pass through the string counts
   both consonants and vowels.
2. have a function which takes a character and returns whether that
   character is a vowel or a consonant
3. consider the logic of what defines whether something is a vowel
   or a consonant (is a character a consonant if it isn't a vowel? what
   about spaces, punctuation?) - these considerations can help you
   design your decision functions.
4. Have each function either be a control function, or an operation
   function - i.e. don't have one function do both.
5. use standard library tools - std::string is a useful way of
   storing characters, and much less error prone than char arrays. You
   can then use algorithms on it, as it's an STL container.

Here's a few bits and pieces which might help you to look at things slightly differently.

```
const std::string vowelsArray("AaEeIiOoUu");
const std::string consonantArray("BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ");
const std::locale loc;


bool isVowel(char c)
{
    return (vowelsArray.find(c) != std::string::npos);
}

bool isConsonant(char c)
{
    return (vowelsArray.find(std::toupper(c, loc)) != std::string::npos);
}

void countChars(std::string userInput, int& vowelCount, int& consonantCount)
{
    for (auto c : userInput)
    {
        if (isVowel(c))
            vowelCount++;
        else if (isConsonant(c))
            consonantCount++;
    }
}
```

I don't want to write the whole thing for you, but if you rethink your design around these simple functions, you might find things a bit easier/more concise. (I did the vowels and consonants slightly differently, you might notice.)

No consideration is made for different languages, which have different characters not in these sets - you might want to think about how those could be handled.

Comment: A couple of those unfortunately we can't use, but I will definitely change a few things in there thanks to your help. Thank you!